# OpenCV Stereo Calibration Rotation Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, calibration

I'm trying to undistort the output of a pair of cameras using the following OpenCV functions:

```
cv::stereoCalibrate(object_points, image_points_left, image_points_right,cameraMatrixLeft, distCoeffsLeft, cameraMatrixRight, distCoeffsRight,cv::Size(sensor_width, sensor_height),R, T, E, F);

cv::stereoRectify(cameraMatrixLeft, distCoeffsLeft, cameraMatrixRight, distCoeffsRight, cv::Size(sensor_width, sensor_height), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);

cv::undistortPoints(src_left, dst_left, cameraMatrixLeft, distCoeffsLeft, R1, P1);
cv::undistortPoints(src_right, dst_right, cameraMatrixRight, distCoeffsRight, R2, P2);
```

As I understand, the function [`cv::undistortPoints`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistortpoints) should also rectify the output using the matrices `R1`, `R2`, `P1` and `P2` according to my stereo camera setup, i.e. set the epipolar lines parallel to the image y-axis and crop the image.

Is this correct?

However, the mapping performed on the points in `src_left` and `src_right` is "tilted", i.e. the undistorted output images are tilted, leaving blank spaces on the boarders (especially in half of the corners) of the image. I believe this tilting comes from the rotation matrices `R1` and `R2` and corresponds to the rotations around the z-axis.

Now here is my question:

- **Why do the (rectified) output images not fill the whole image space?**

Answer (score 3):

During rectification and undistortion the image can be translated and/or rotated depending on orientation of the stereo cameras.

Obviously, if you will leave the original resolution for the transformed image - you will lose some information around the border. E.g. consider that there's no translation, but you have to rotate one of the images 45 degrees clockwise and use the same resolution - the corners will be "blank".

The common solution is to find a largest "inscribed" rectangle and scale it up to the original resolution.

You can use `initUndistortRectifyMap` for that instead of `undistortPoints`.

For your `stereoRectify` call, the calls to the `initUndistortRectifyMap` will look as follows:

- left: `initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrixLeft, distCoeffsLeft, R1, P1, cv::Size(sensor_width, sensor_height), CV_32FC1, map_left_1, map_left_2);`
- right: `initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrixRight, distCoeffsRight, R2, P2, cv::Size(sensor_width, sensor_height), CV_32FC1, map_right_1, map_right_2);`

This will get you the maps for a call to `remap`:

- `remap(left, left_rectified, map_left_1, map_left_2, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);`
- `remap(right, right_rectified, map_right_1, map_right_2, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);`

Comment: Thank you @Sergei. Since I only have a sparse set of image points, I wanted to use 'undistortPoints'.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your problem. You call stereoRectify in your original solution. I assume it gives you the desired output. So, I don't see a problem to call initUndistortRectifyMap which seems to do what you need - handle the blank borders. What am I missing?

Comment: I think I didn't properly read the initUndistortRectifyMap documentation, your suggested approach absolutely makes sense. Thanks again!